# SQL query execute statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am a beginner at SQL. I want to execute this query, but having difficulty in executing it. "Provide the S# and SNAME of all suppliers who belong to the same city as Jones does? (Jones exclusive)". Table is down below

[image: TABLE S]

Comment: Looks like homework?

Comment: Nope, it's a book which i'm currently reading.

Comment: Please do not post images. Provide the sample data as text ( or more preferably as DDL and DML) so that answerers can quickly emulate your problem and find you a solution.

Comment: I don't know how to post tables as a text, sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is actually asking you two things: what city is associated with Jones? Apparently Paris. Now that we know this, the next question (is show's up first, but you have to think inside to outside here) is, what are the S# and SNAMEs of all rows with the city Paris.

So, you could first execute `SELECT CITY FROM S WHERE SNAME = "Jones"`, save the result and use it in the next query `SELECT S#, SNAME FROM S WHERE CITY = "The results of your last query"`

We can condense this down to

```
SELECT S#, SNAME FROM S WHERE CITY = (SELECT CITY FROM S WHERE NAME = "JONES")
```

As the query excludes Jones you can just add

```
AND NAME != "JONES"
```

Answer (score 3):

Hoping i understood your problem correctly.

Please check below query.

```
select s# , sname 
from S 
where city in (select city from S where sname='Jones') 
and     sname<>'Jones';
```

Comment: giving me this error "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'."

Comment: @Sami Hoping you are using query after edit. Please use updated query, Raymond Nijland Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this in several ways.  All of the answers posted thus far are perfectly valid and would work just fine; but there are alternatives.  Personally, I would use a self-join for this:

```
SELECT
     S2.S#
    ,S2.SName
FROM S
INNER JOIN S S2
    ON S.S# <> S2.S#
    AND S.City = S2.City
WHERE S.SName = 'Jones'
;
```